# JUnit working in terminal but not in intellij

Tags: spring, junit, intellij-idea

I have a problem running junit test in intellij. The error I get is as follow:

```
 SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/grails/dist/grails-plugin-log4j-2.3.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/grails/lib/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple/jars/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/dev/maven/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.7/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory]
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [C:\dev\projects\SlaveDriver\target\classes\com\r\slavedriver\service\ServerDetailsImpl.class]; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: file [C:\dev\projects\SlaveDriver\target\classes\com\r\slavedriver\service\ServerDetailsImpl.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    ... 12 more
Caused by: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: file [C:\dev\projects\SlaveDriver\target\classes\com\r\slavedriver\service\ServerDetailsImpl.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

I found a few posts about this problem and it seems to be related to jdk or old spring versions but I have everything up to date, jdk1.8 and spring 4
any advice on what could be the problem?

THanks

ps:

```
  <properties>
        <!-- Generic properties -->
        <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <!--Logging -->
        <org.slf4j.version>1.7.7</org.slf4j.version>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <org.springframework.version>4.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
        <!-- Spring MVC: Json parsing -->
        <com.fasterxml.jackson.version>2.4.0</com.fasterxml.jackson.version>
        <!-- Spring Data -->
        <org.springframework.data-jpa.version>1.5.0.RELEASE</org.springframework.data-jpa.version>
        <org.hibernate.jpa.version>1.0.1.Final</org.hibernate.jpa.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.2.9.Final</hibernate.version>
        <mysql.connector.version>5.1.30</mysql.connector.version>
        <!-- Plugin for load database configuration -->
        <flywaydb.version>3.0</flywaydb.version>
        <!-- Test -->
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Logging: Required by spring context -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>

            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring MVC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring MVC: Object mapping -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${com.fasterxml.jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${com.fasterxml.jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring MVC: Servlet dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Data -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.data-jpa.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Data: Transaction Managment -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Data: Mysql connector for the database -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Testing dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <plugins>
            <!-- To set the proper jdk version in the classpath -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Plugin to execute the sql migration scripts -->
            <!-- Usage: mvn flyway:clean compile flyway:migrate -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
                <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${flywaydb.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost/slave_driver</url>
                    <user>root</user>
                    <password>h0liday</password>
                    <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
                    <locations>
                        <location>db/app/migrations</location>
                    </locations>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                        <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <port>8080</port>
                    <contextFile>src/test/resources/tomcat-context.xml</contextFile>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: Make sure that you have the same compiler settings in IntelliJ and maven.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem :

```
ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: file [C:\dev\projects\SlaveDriver\target\classes\com\rentalcars\slavedriver\service\ServerDetailsImpl.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

Only spring 4 supports java 8 apparently.

And also, view your maven depenedcy diagram, and exclude the duplicate sl4j bindings.

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            <scope>${defaultScope}</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Apparently he uses log4j (judging from the LOG4j messages) I would exlcude `slf4j-simple`.

Comment: I have added the pom.xml file,not sure what exactly is duplicate and needs to be removed.

Comment: richgt click on pom > diagrams > you can view duplicate dependencies. But you need to change spring versin or jdk version first

Comment: what version do I need to change jdk and spring to? I have already jdk 1.8 and spring 4.0.5 being used

if i right clock on the pom.xml > in diagrams the only option I see is show changes

Comment: the error says it has something to do with ASM classreader failing to parse class file